# fsockopen() error : Network is unreachable port 43 in php

Tags: networking, php

i've writed some Php code that lookup for domain (whois) but it fails !!

this is some of my code :

```
function checkdomain($server,$domain){
global $response;
    $connection = fsockopen($server,43);
    fputs($connection, "domain " . $domain . "\r\n");
    while(!feof($connection)){
        $response .= fgets($connection, 4096);
    }
    fclose($connection);
}
checkdomain("whois.crsnic.net","www.example.com");
```

the code work on my localhost ( apache,php,mysql, OS -> Win XP ) but when i uploaded it to 
my host (Linux) it failed.
and i always see the Below Error/message :

```
Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to whois.crsnic.net:43 
(Network is unreachable) in /home/hamid0011/public_html/whois/whois.php on line 37
```

what should i do ?
is this my host's problem or whois server ( but it work in localhost ) or my code?

Comment: try a manual lookup with the `whois` command or `telnet whois.crsnic.net 43` and see if works there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your host has blocked outgoing communications on port 43, or the shared server IP you're using has hit the WHOIS server so hard that they've resorted to blocking your IP (not very likely).

In any case, you'll need to contact your host.

Obtaining a `traceroute whois.crsnic.net` might be useful, if you have shell access. If you can paste one here, we might also be able to debug your issue better (the outputs of the `whois` command and the `telnet` one would also be useful as SvenW has said).

Comment: the problem was in host, my host manager opened the port 43, thank you for answer

Comment: No problem - if could please accept the answer by ticking pressing the hollow/green tick on the left, I would appreciate it, thanks :-)

Comment: ofcourse this is right, Ad thank you Again for your attention